# Grouping elements on the same level

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having an issue with my transform and was hoping for some ideas, I'm dealing with a really flat input document where all important nodes are siblings of one another.

It kind of looks like this:

```
<title1> Rule 51 </title1>
<p> text here </p>
<p> text here </p>
<note> Source </note>
<p> text here </p>
<title1> Rule 52 </title1>
<p> text here </p>
<p> text here </p>
<note> Source </note>
<p> text here </p>
```

My goal is for this input to look like this:

```
  <section>
       <title1> Rule 51 </title1>
       <p> text here </p>
       <p> text here </p>
       <note> Source </note>
           <p> text here </p>
   </section>

   <section>
       <title1> Rule 52 </title1>
       <p> text here </p>
       <p> text here </p>
       <p> text here </p>
       <p> text here </p>
       <note> Source </note>
           <p> text here </p>
   </section>
```

As you can see above my main goal is grouping each title1 and all of it's following siblings until it hits another title1 into a section element. Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what IDE will you be using to do this with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<!-- Change the match pattern to match the parent of the input you showed. -->
<xsl:template match="blockquote">
  <xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="h:h4" select="*">
    <section>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
```

in XSLT 2.0.

If you can only use XSLT 1.0, look up [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), and holler if you need help.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the syntax? Have never come across using for-each-group.

Comment: @Laterade: If `<h:h4>` is the start of each section, then you want to do your for-each-group on the children of the *parent* of `h:h4`, so your match pattern needs to match the parent of `h:h4`. Other than that I believe your code looks good. (The code you just removed!)

Comment: Sorry about not changing the names but <h:h4> is <section> in my question above. Basically the parent on h:h4 in my document is the element <blockquote> that encompasses the entire document pretty much.  And the children of <blockquote> are all on the same level.

Comment: I'm confused. `<h:h4>` is `<section>`, which is in your output document. But its parent is `<blockquote>`, which is in your input document?

Comment: oh wait I'm sorry, <h:h4> is <title1> in my input, and <section> is just something I want to wrap my group in on my output. And <blockquote> is the parent of <title1> in the input document.